# copy list from sharepoint site to another (SP 2010)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i have this problem.

I have to copy a sharepoint list from one site to another with all the attachements without deleting anything.
The sites are running on different farms. 
Example:
http://server1.domain.local/subsite1/lists/list1/

http://server2.domain.local/subsite2/lists/list2/

i have to run the scripts onto server2.
the error i get is:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The Web application at http://server1.domain.local/subsite1/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. 
If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application."
```

how can i resolve with powershell scripts?

many thanks

mauro

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `1` or `2` in the URL

Comment: just a refuse... those are not the proper names. i modify the post. thanks

Comment: Could you show us the script you're using to try to copy the list?